# Why is Git on WSL2 with SouceTree so slow for me?

Tags: git, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, atlassian-sourcetree, wsl-2

My environment is as follows.

- Windows10（version 2004, build 19041.572）
- 64 bit OS
- On WSL2, I use Ubuntu（Ubuntu-20.04）
- I use git with SourceTree.

I use docker-compose to develop Web services. Running docker-compose on Windows is very slow for accessing web pages. I created a docker environment in the Ubuntu's Home folder on WSL2. Web site data (Laravel) is installed in the docker environment on WSL2 and managed by git.

How can i improve the speed of SourceTree on WSL2? Git on Windows is faster.

Comment: The same happens here. So slow that it's not really usable. It also lists a lot of unchanged files as unstaged (line endings or permissions maybe?).

Comment: I found WSLGIT( https://github.com/andy-5/wslgit ). But it did not  work on SourceTree.

Comment: @zenzenzenfone Can you please clearify where you are running SourceTree and how you access the local repository? I suppose you are running SourceTree in Windows and accessing the files by `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\...`. Please add those information to your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately WSL2 [has an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4197) with filesystem performance on `/mnt`.

Might be an option to `checkout` your repo into container's `/home`, instead of `/mnt/...`, if you don't need to edit it from windows.

Running Docker from a Linux container on windows will not help.

UPD: The same issue can appear on a large project w/o mounting anything, but still accessing repo inside WSL by `\\wsl$` path from Windows. The issue still open.

Comment: Performance in SourceTree and IDEs (except Visual Studio Code with Remote - WSL) are facing imense performance problems, even when the project is placed directly inside of the Linux file system (like `/home` or `/env`). I suppose @zenzenzenfone is using SourceTree on Windows (accessing the files by `\\wsl$`) and not inside of WSL what should be clarified in his / her question.

Comment: I found a lot of similar issues with "docker-compose running slow", or "npm run serve running slow". In all similar situations, it's about low FS performance between Windows/Linux filesystems. So doesn't matter are talking about a specific path or specific software - heavy IO with lots of files involved - will cause the same issue. The main point - the issue in WSL2 exists.

Comment: Paths do matter. When your project is located e. g. in `/home/user/project` and you are starting docker-compose from within a Linux distribution bash, it is lightning fast. Calling docker-compose in a Windows CLI (in `\\wsl$\distribution_name\home\user\project`) is really slow even though it is exactly the same docker-compose file. And vice versa - calling `/mnt/c/my-project` from Linux is slow and `C:\my-project` in Windows again fast. So the conclusion is, WSL(2) is only slow when accessed from Windows and NTFS is only slow when accessed from Linux.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is to use git tasks/command inside the IDE that supports WSL.

I use Visual Studio Code inside WSL 2 and use git extensions to do git tasks/commands. The performance is superb! :-D

Answer (score 1):

I know link-only answers are frowned upon, but I found this:
https://gist.github.com/jasonboukheir/3fdab92ece236744528447a4f7f5de00

It's a clever, if somewhat kludgy solution, whereby you end up using WSL git for Linux-y paths, and Windows git for Windows-y paths.

Comment: Interesting!
I don't know much about it, but I'll give it a try.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced huge performace improvements by always launching the terminal (which in turn starts wsl and and VM) as an administrator and first after that launching sourcetree as an administrator.

My best guess is that this skips a lot of security checks which makes it run faster. If anyone has any insight in to this or can reproduce my findings please let me know.

**Important!** Running programs as an administrator can be a cause for concern as this can lead to security risks! Always asses the risks on a case to case basis.